# Migration Error from unknown attribute :date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a Codeacademy calendar app, and I am hitting an error with my rake db:seed. Could anyone help explain the error, and how to get around it?

```
Eric-Parks-MacBook-Pro-2:calendar ericpark$ rake db:seed
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285: warning: circular argument reference - now
    rake aborted!
    ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: date
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:50:in `rescue in _assign_attribute'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:32:in `block in assign_attributes'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `each'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `assign_attributes'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:452:in `init_attributes'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
    /Users/ericpark/rails_projects/calendar/db/seeds.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:543:in `load_seed'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:184:in `load_seed'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:173:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    NoMethodError: undefined method `date=' for #<Day id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:206:in `method_missing'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `public_send'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:32:in `block in assign_attributes'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `each'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `assign_attributes'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:452:in `init_attributes'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
    /Users/ericpark/rails_projects/calendar/db/seeds.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:543:in `load_seed'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:184:in `load_seed'
    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:173:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    Tasks: TOP => db:seed
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I manipulated the migration file.

Seeds File:

```
# This file should contain all the record creation needed to seed the database with its default values.
# The data can then be loaded with the rake db:seed (or created alongside the db with db:setup).
#
# Examples:
#
#   cities = City.create([{ name: 'Chicago' }, { name: 'Copenhagen' }])
#   Mayor.create(name: 'Emanuel', city: cities.first)

d1 = Day.create(date: DateTime.parse('11th Jan 2015 00:00 AM'))
Event.create(name: "Ben Visiting", from: DateTime.parse('11th Jan 2015 00:00 AM'), to: DateTime.parse('12th Jan 2015 00:00 AM'), location: "", day_id: d1.id)

d2 = Day.create(date: DateTime.parse('12th Jan 2015 00:00 AM'))

d3 = Day.create(date: DateTime.parse('13th Jan 2015 00:00 AM'))
Event.create(name: "Taco Tuesday", from: DateTime.parse('13th Jan 2015 01:00 PM'), to: DateTime.parse('13th Jan 2015 03:00 PM'), location: "Brooklyn Taco Co. 120 Essex Street New York, NY 10002", day_id: d3.id)

d4 = Day.create(date: DateTime.parse('14th Jan 2015 00:00 AM'))
Event.create(name: "Pottery Painting", from: DateTime.parse('14th Jan 2015 06:00 PM'), to: DateTime.parse('14th Jan 2015 07:00 PM'), location: "The Art Cafe CH 326 Troy Avenue Brooklyn, NY 11213", day_id: d4.id)

d5 = Day.create(date: DateTime.parse('15th Jan 2015 00:00 AM'))

d6 = Day.create(date: DateTime.parse('16th Jan 2015 00:00 AM'))
Event.create(name: "Casual Friday", from: DateTime.parse('16th Jan 2015 00:00 AM'), to: DateTime.parse('17th Jan 2015 00:00 AM'), location: "", day_id: d6.id)
Event.create(name: "Running", from: DateTime.parse('16th Jan 2015 08:00 PM'), to: DateTime.parse('16th Jan 2015 08:30 PM'), location: "", day_id: d6.id)
Event.create(name: "Grocery Shopping", from: DateTime.parse('16th Jan 2015 09:00 PM'), to: DateTime.parse('16th Jan 2015 09:30 AM'), location: "", day_id: d6.id)

d6 = Day.create(date: DateTime.parse('17th Jan 2015 00:00 AM'))
```

Here is the attached seed file.

Comment: can you show us your seed file?

Comment: It seems error is coming from line: /Users/ericpark/rails_projects/calendar/db/seeds.rb:9, Have you changed this line, and to what if you have.

Comment: I felt as though the error came from :date in the migration file, maybe it isn't being inputted properly?

Comment: have you run `rake db:migrate`? you might have pending migration(s), which may add the `date` column to the `days` table

Comment: Yup I ran a db:migrate but it still does not populate the :date column within my schema.

Answer (score 1):

From the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `date=' for #<Day id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

It seems that your table `days` doesn't have any date column in it. There can be following reasons:

1. You forgot to run an existing migration
2. You need to add date column in this table
3. You are wrongly passing `date` field in insert statement.

Comment: Here is my migration file for days ```class CreateDays < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    create_table :days do |t|
      t.datetime :date
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
``` I ran a rake db:migrate, and it came with this warning: /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285: warning: circular argument reference - now. Why would the :date not be placed into the table?

Comment: This is probably because `date` is a reserved keyword in rails. [source](http://siwei.me/blog/posts/ruby-rails-reserved-words-complete)

Comment: Hmm this is from a Codeacademy excercise for creating a calendar. It says to *Open the migration file in db/migrate/ for the days table, and add the following columns:a datetime column called date*. Would this be incorrect then? Should I be renaming the column date to something else?